# Slideshow shows the other slide underneath

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, banner

I currently have this slider, but when i load the website, I can see the other slide on top. Then for 2 secs it loads, and then it disappears and the slideshow starts and works fluently.

I can't seem to figure out what is causing it. Would be great if someone could help me out.

Here is my JAVASCRIPT, CSS & HTML:

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(0)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(0)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  4000);
```

```css
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

#slideshow > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}

#slideshow {
  margin-top: 35px;
  background-image: url('../images/Untitled-1.jpg');
  height: 360px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.banner_columns {
    display: flex;
}

.img {
  margin-top: -35px;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
}

.column-one {
    order: 1;
}

.column-two {
    order: 2;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
}

.header1 {
  color: #1e1e1c;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
}

.p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.button1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  padding: 3px 30px;
  background-color: #b52323;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button_1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 3px 30px;
  background-color: #b52323;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 22px;
  background-color: #656565;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
<div class="bgbanner">
  <div class="banner_columns1">
    <div class="column column-one">
      <div class="banner">
        <img class="img" src="images/Bog-til-hjemmeside2.png" width="380">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-two">
      <h1 class="header1">“Velfungerende roman, der effektivt skifter <br>mellem krigstraumer, flugt og bekymringer. <br>En hæderlig bog om den værste krig i EU.”</h1>
      <p class="p">- Kristeligt Dagblad, 2013</p>
      <a class="button_1" href="https://www.saxo.com/dk/knacker_karsten-skov_haeftet_9788792975102">Køb nu</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bgbanner">
  <div class="banner_columns1">
    <div class="column column-one">
      <div class="banner">
        <img class="img" src="images/Bog-til-hjemmeside.png" width="380">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-two">
      <h1 class="header1">“Velfungerende roman, der effektivt skifter <br>mellem krigstraumer, flugt og bekymringer. <br>En hæderlig bog om den værste krig i EU.”</h1>
      <p class="p">- Kristeligt Dagblad, 2013</p>
      <a class="button2" href="bibliografi_knacker.html">Læs mere...</a>
      <a class="button1" href="https://www.saxo.com/dk/knacker_karsten-skov_haeftet_9788792975102">Køb nu</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to the CSS

```css
#slideshow > div:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

and remove

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
```

which is kicking in too late

```js
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
      .fadeOut(0)
      .next()
      .fadeIn(0)
      .end()
      .appendTo('#slideshow');
  }, 4000);
});
```

```css
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
#slideshow > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
#slideshow {
  margin-top: 35px;
  background-image: url('../images/Untitled-1.jpg');
  height: 360px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#slideshow > div:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
.banner_columns {
  display: flex;
}
.img {
  margin-top: -35px;
  margin-left: 190px;
}
.column {
  flex: 1;
}
.column-one {
  order: 1;
}
.column-two {
  order: 2;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
.header1 {
  color: #1e1e1c;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
}
.p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.button1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  padding: 3px 30px;
  background-color: #b52323;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button_1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 3px 30px;
  background-color: #b52323;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 22px;
  background-color: #656565;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<base href="http://jakobhoeg.com/projekta/"/><!-- remove this before using -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <div class="bgbanner">
    <div class="banner_columns1">
      <div class="column column-one">
        <div class="banner">
          <img class="img" src="images/Bog-til-hjemmeside2.png" width="380">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column column-two">
        <h1 class="header1">“Velfungerende roman, der effektivt skifter <br>mellem krigstraumer, flugt og bekymringer. <br>En hæderlig bog om den værste krig i EU.”</h1>
        <p class="p">- Kristeligt Dagblad, 2013</p>
        <a class="button_1" href="https://www.saxo.com/dk/knacker_karsten-skov_haeftet_9788792975102">Køb nu</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bgbanner">
    <div class="banner_columns1">
      <div class="column column-one">
        <div class="banner">
          <img class="img" src="images/Bog-til-hjemmeside.png" width="380">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column column-two">
        <h1 class="header1">“Velfungerende roman, der effektivt skifter <br>mellem krigstraumer, flugt og bekymringer. <br>En hæderlig bog om den værste krig i EU.”</h1>
        <p class="p">- Kristeligt Dagblad, 2013</p>
        <a class="button2" href="bibliografi_knacker.html">Læs mere...</a>
        <a class="button1" href="https://www.saxo.com/dk/knacker_karsten-skov_haeftet_9788792975102">Køb nu</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

the problem here seems to be that the styles for the two images

`bgbanner`

appear to be displayed so until the javascript doesn't kick in both are shown.

Try to hide the one you do not want to show at the beginning the same way the fade out method is doing it, changing its opacity to:

`opacity : 0`

Comment: Hey guys, can you let me know what is wrong with this answer? Thanks! :)